# Отслеживание нажатой клавиши Ctrl

Tags: javascript

Ребят, мне нужно отследить нажатую клавишу <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Я отслеживаю событие `window.onkeydown`. Если нажата клавиша Ctrl, то переменная `__ctrl = true`. И отслеживаю еще 2 события: `window.onkeyup` и `window.onblur`. Если `window.onkeyup` сказал мне, что была отпущена клавиша <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, то переменная `__ctrl = false`. И если же вызвано событие `window.onblur`, то тоже переменная `__ctrl = false`.

Вопрос:
Правильно ли все это? В принципе все работает. Или надо отслеживать еще какие то события. Т.е. не возникнет такой ситуации, что по сути клавиша <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> отпущена, а переменная `__ctrl = true`?

Пример:

```
var __ctrl = false;

window.onkeydown = function( e ){
    if( e.keyCode == 17 ){
        __ctrl = true;
    }
};

window.onkeyup = function( e ){
    if( e.keyCode == 17 ){
        __ctrl = false;
    }
};

window.onblue = function(){
    __ctrl = false;
};
```

Эта переменная `__ctrl` нужна для того, чтобы например пользователь хочет выделить несколько элементов зажав контрол и щелкая мышкой.

Comment: В любом случае, свойство `ctrlKey` есть у объекта типа `KeyboardEvent` в [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey), так что рассчитывать на него можно.

Comment: Вот оно как, оказывается. А почему не просто использовать упомянутое свойство `ctrlKey`?

Comment: Если не трудно можно пример?

Comment: [В этом вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374915/javascript-detect-ctrl-key-pressed-or-up-keypress-event-doest-trigger) есть пример во втором ответе. А вообще ведь и из документации понятно что это такое и как это использовать.